# windows store app receipt verification

Tags: c#, uwp

I am working on a paid `Universal Windows Platform` app. where i need to confirm the payment receipt.i am not sure which of the receipt element is unique per user. so that if the user got the same app on another device he may be allowed to proceed. here's the app receipt.

```
<Receipt Version="1.0" ReceiptDate="2012-08-30T23:10:05Z" CertificateId="b809e47cd0110a4db043b3f73e83acd917fe1336" ReceiptDeviceId="4e362949-acc3-fe3a-e71b-89893eb4f528">
<AppReceipt Id="8ffa256d-eca8-712a-7cf8-cbf5522df24b" AppId="55428GreenlakeApps.CurrentAppSimulatorEventTest_z7q3q7z11crfr" PurchaseDate="2012-06-04T23:07:24Z" LicenseType="Full" />
<ProductReceipt Id="6bbf4366-6fb2-8be8-7947-92fd5f683530" ProductId="Product1" PurchaseDate="2012-08-30T23:08:52Z" ExpirationDate="2012-09-02T23:08:49Z" ProductType="Durable" AppId="55428GreenlakeApps.CurrentAppSimulatorEventTest_z7q3q7z11crfr" />
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
        <Reference URI="">
            <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <DigestValue>cdiU06eD8X/w1aGCHeaGCG9w/kWZ8I099rw4mmPpvdU=</DigestValue>
        </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>SjRIxS/2r2P6ZdgaR9bwUSa6ZItYYFpKLJZrnAa3zkMylbiWjh9oZGGng2p6/gtBHC2dSTZlLbqnysJjl7mQp/A3wKaIkzjyRXv3kxoVaSV0pkqiPt04cIfFTP0JZkE5QD/vYxiWjeyGp1dThEM2RV811sRWvmEs/hHhVxb32e8xCLtpALYx3a9lW51zRJJN0eNdPAvNoiCJlnogAoTToUQLHs72I1dECnSbeNPXiG7klpy5boKKMCZfnVXXkneWvVFtAA1h2sB7ll40LEHO4oYN6VzD+uKd76QOgGmsu9iGVyRvvmMtahvtL1/pxoxsTRedhKq6zrzCfT8qfh3C1w==</SignatureValue>
</Signature>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this required a little digging on my behalf and unfortunately it will require a bit of setup on yours. You will need to set up a Web App in Azure AD to store customer ID's and link them to purchases. These keys expire every 90 days, so you will have to regenerate upon expiration. I'm linking the articles because I feel MSDN has elaborated well enough.

[Setting Up Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service)

[Generating new keys upon expiration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/renew-a-windows-store-id-key)

FINALLY, you may use GetCustomerCollectionsIdAsync() or GetCustomerPurchaseIdAsync() (whichever one suits you best) to retrieve their purchase.

[Getting the purchase ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp#Windows_ApplicationModel_Store_CurrentApp_GetCustomerPurchaseIdAsync_)

Comment: thanks for your comment.can you see the default receipt i have posted. like there must be something unique in it for a single person who has made a purchase. and if the same person need to have the same app for another device he must not pay for this. but he will have a license for this app.what i want to make sure is that whether he would have the same certificate on both device.

Comment: Quoted from MSDN: "Currently, the only way to create a Microsoft Store ID key is by calling a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) API from client code in your app. The generated key represents the identity of the user who is currently signed in to the Microsoft Store on the device." Please read the articles. They are there to help you, and the way Microsoft has done it is very secure and honestly simple if you give them a read. But to answer your question, no. The receipt is just that - a receipt. It contains only information about your app, and the purchase itself.